# How to use elastic search in vue ? how to store some data in elastic search?

Tags: vue.js, elasticsearch, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to store some data i.e (Wishlist info) in elastic search index,

how can i use/include elastic search in vue ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple libraries and and tutorials out there. 
Some pointers to get you started:

- A [tutorial](https://medium.appbase.io/building-booksearch-application-using-vue-and-elasticsearch-a39615f4d6b3) using Appbase.io's [ReactiveSearch](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactivesearch/vue)
- A [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-real-time-search-engine-with-node-vue-and-elasticsearch) from DigitalOcean describing both the elastic search side and access to it using Vue
- A [simple wrapper](https://github.com/InnerSearch/vue-innersearch) that makes querying ES from a Vue app easy.